# Google cloub build changed (for no reason?)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I have a nodejs project running on app engine. This worked fine until yesterday. My package.json is also uploaded becuase it contains dependencies and start script. When I deploay a google cloud build is automatically run. Since yesterstay it also tries to run "npm run build". Of course this fails because I don't upload any source files.

I did not configure this and I'm wondering why the behaviour changed.

To upload I use the gcloud comand:

`gcloud app deploy --version v1`

My app.yml looks like:

```
# [START app_yaml]
runtime: nodejs16
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1

entrypoint: npm run cloud-start

handlers:
- url: /api/.*
  script: auto
  secure: always

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|json)(|\.map))$
  static_files: dist/www/\1
  upload: dist/www/(.*)(|\.map)
  secure: always
  expiration: "100d 0h"

- url: /|(.*)|index.html
  static_files: dist/www/index.html
  upload: dist/www/index.html
  expiration: "0d 0h"
  secure: always

# [END app_yaml]
```

.cloudignore:

```
# Ignore everything
/[!.]*
/.?*

# Except the Cloud Function files we want to deploy
!/package.json
!/package-lock.json
!/dist/**

#!include:.gitignore
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got hit by this today as well, and it took me the whole day to finally figure out.

This is 100% a Google functional change for the gcloud app deploy script for nodejs.

Thankfully, there's a simple workaround below, but first I want to rant and give context: this afternoon when I deployed with a totally minor and unrelated change I received a buildbreaker. Everything worked fine locally, so I tried re-deploying a previous build to the dev environment. It, too, failed.

After researching, I found the same thing you did; an unexpected call to `npm build`. After a *lot more* research, I found the workaround.

It turns out that Google arbitrarily decided a few days ago to start running `build` if it exists in `package.json` as a fallback when there is no `gcp-build` script. Thankfully, including a blank `gcp-build` script in `package.json` fixes the issue. See below for an example

I never received a notice from google cloud that they were doing this.

I, like you, pre-package my build using the npm build script in my `package.json`, then run `gcloud deploy` while suppressing the original source folder.

I, like you, did not include a `gcp-build` script, because I had no special build needs.

**Workaround**

Add `"gcp-build": ""` to the `scripts` section of your `package.json`.

Example:

```
{
    "name": "myapp",
    "main": "mybuild/index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "build": "tsc",
      "start": "node mybuild/index.js",
      "gcp-build": ""
    },
}
```

If there is a `gcp-build` command in the scripts section, Google Cloud will try to run that, rather than `build`. If it's blank, it will do nothing but most imporantly will not fall back to `build`.

**Future Reference**

This is current information and there is a very good chance google will change this functionality very soon. I will try to keep an eye on developments and update as necessary

*update*
Looks like google has rolled this out to cloud functions as well.

Comment: I did not even push any changes. i suddenly noticed my webhooks failing. they only trigger about once a month. and i suddenly get strange runtime errors. Apparently this change also hits already-deployed cloud functions when they need to be automatically rebuilt. Absolutely unacceptable behaviour for production software. Honestly the risk of Google doing this is reason enough for us to look for alternative edge function providers.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud build is running the "npm run build" command during deployment, you have not uploaded any source file it causing deployment failure. Update the app.yaml file to specify the different "entrypoint" that doesn't trigger the "npm run build" command.

Comment: The endpoint in my `app.yml` doesn't trigger the build comand and has no dependent comands. I use github actions to deploy. If I re-run the deployment of an old commit which has worked fine before, it now fails. That means the change must be somewhere else, not in the repo.

Comment: update Github actions to trigger the deployment check the GitHub Actions workflow file and make sure it's not  triggering any build steps that include "npm run build" command.

Comment: It also fails locally using `glcoud`. I just mentioned GH actions because it allowes to re-run an old build with exaclty the same source files, same app.yml, same gh action script. 
3 days ago this build succeeded but now it fails. So it can't be the script.

Comment: @MarcS82 if you're still having this issue, I posted a workaround as an answer. add a blank script named `gcp-build` to `packge.json` scripts section.

Comment: @RobinaMirbahar there isn't any way to change entrypoints and avoid this. The issue is that if there is a `build` script in `package.json` but no `gcp-build` script, google will now run `build` always.